# If $\eta(i)=k+i$ for every $1\le i\le \ell$ and $\eta(\ell+i)=i$ for every $1\le i\le k$, then the signature of $\eta$ is $(-1)^{k\ell}$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> Consider the permutation in $S_{k+\ell}$ defined by $$\eta=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
> 1 & \cdots & \ell & \ell+1 & \cdots & \ell+k\\
> k+1 & \cdots & k+\ell & 1 & \cdots & k
> \end{array}\right].$$
>   Prove that $\mbox{sgn}(\eta)=\left(-1\right)^{k\ell}$.

I am trying to find a way to show that $\eta$ is a product of $k\ell$ transpositions, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what is the signature of $\gamma$?

$$\gamma=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1 & \cdots & \ell & \ell+1 & \cdots & \ell+k - 1 &\ell + k\\
2 & \cdots & \ell + 1 & \ell+2 & \cdots & \ell +k & 1
\end{array}\right]$$

What do you know about the behaviour of the signature under composition? Can you compose $\eta$ using $\gamma$?

Comment: I am a bit confused about your definition of $\gamma$. What is it supposed to map $2$ and $l+k$ to?

Comment: @Eigenfield It's simply the permutation formed by a circular left shift of 1. $2$ maps to $3$ and $l+k$ maps to $1$.

Comment: There is a typo there, $l$ should get mapped to $l+1$ and $l+1$ should get mapped to $l+2$.

Comment: I understand know. $\gamma ^{k}=\eta$ and the rest follows from the fact that $sgn$ is a homomorphism. Thanks.

Comment: @Eigenfield Oops, sorry for the typo, fixed.